# Sql execute query on multiple rows

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

this query works:

```
$player_id = $_POST['player_id'];//array

$ids = explode(',',$player_id);
$in = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($ids), '%d'));

$wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("DELETE FROM {$player_table} WHERE id IN ($in)", $ids));
```

this does not:

```
$disabled = $_POST['disabled'];
$media_id = $_POST['media_id'];//array

$ids = explode(',',$media_id);
$in = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($ids), '%d'));

$wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("UPDATE {$media_table} SET disabled = %s WHERE id IN ($in)", $disabled, $ids));
```

I cant figure out why.

Comment: Someone with almost 4k rep should know "this doesn't work" is not a helpful description of a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to spread the IDS into separate arguments to match all the `%s` in the query. Use `...` syntax to do this.

```
$wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("UPDATE {$media_table} SET disabled = %s WHERE id IN ($in)", $disabled, ...$ids));
```